Show that $\exp(D_s)$ converges strongly on $L^2$ to $T_1$ as $s \to 0$.
Consider $L^2 = L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Given any real number $s$, define $T : L^2 \to L^2$ by setting
$$(T_s x)(t) = x(t+s) \quad \text{for every} \ x \in L^2 \ \text{and} \ t \in \mathbb{R}.$$
For $s \neq 0$, define also
$$D_s = \frac{1}{2s} (T_s - T_{-s}).$$
Show that $\exp(D_s)$ converges strongly on $L^2$ to $T_1$ as $s \to 0$. (Hint: The Fourier transform can be useful here.)
My solution
I found that
$$\lim_{s \to 0} \mathcal{F}[D_s] = -\lim_{s \to 0}  i \xi \frac{\sin(s \xi)}{ s \xi } \hat{x}(\xi) = -i\xi \hat{x}(\xi)\equiv \mathcal{F}[\frac{d}{dt}x].$$
Also, it is evident that $\mathcal{F}(T_1 x)=e^{- i\xi} \hat{x}(\xi)$.
When I affect by the Fourier transform on the operator $e^{D_s}= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(D_s)^n}{n!}$, it seems that for the solution to be true I need to have $(\mathcal{F}[(D_s)^n])= (\mathcal{F}(D_s))^n$! Which is not always true s far as I recall!
Could you please clarify...

Taking the Fourier transform of $D_s(f)$ and letting $s\to 0$ will probably not work directly because $D_s(f)$ does not converge for all $f\in L^2$ as $s\to0$ (basically because not every such $f$ is differentiable).
Let's look at $\mathcal F(\exp(D_s)f)$. Note that $D_s^n=\frac1{(2s)^n}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk(-1)^kT_{s(n-2k)}$. Then\begin{align*}
\mathcal F(\exp(D_s)f)(\xi) &= \sum_{n\geq0}\frac1{n!}\frac1{(2s)^n}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk(-1)^k\mathcal F(T_{s(n-2k)}f)(\xi)\\
&=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac1{n!}\frac1{(2s)^n}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk(-1)^ke^{is(n-2k)\xi}\hat f(\xi)\\
&=\sum_{k\geq0}\sum_{n=k}^\infty\frac1{(2s)^n}\frac1{k!(n-k)!}(-1)^ke^{is(n-2k)\xi}\hat f(\xi)\\
&=\sum_{k\geq0}\frac1{k!}(-e^{-2is\xi})^k\sum_{n=k}^\infty\frac1{(2s)^n}\frac1{(n-k)!}e^{isn\xi}\hat f(\xi)\\
&=\exp(\frac{e^{is\xi}}{2s})\hat f(\xi)\sum_{k\geq0}\frac1{k!}\frac1{(2s)^k}(-e^{-2is\xi})^ke^{ik\xi}\\
&=\exp(\frac{e^{is\xi}}{2s})\hat f(\xi)\exp(-\frac{-e^{is\xi}}{2s})\\
&=\exp(i\frac{\sin(s\xi)}s)\hat f(\xi)\\
\end{align*}
Now as $s\to0$ this converges to $\exp(i\xi)\hat f(\xi)$ in $L^2$ (pointwise convergence and uniformly bounded by $L^2$ function $\hat f$) which is $\mathcal F(T_1f)(\xi)$.

I thought the argument would be using the semigroups

I suppose one might be able to argue like this: Let $A$ be the strong limit of the $D_s$ (so the generator of the group $(T_s)_s$, it is the derivative with domain $H^1$), then from semigroups we know that $\exp(A)$ (defined using functional calculus for unbounded operators) is $T_1$, one could then try to argue that $\exp(D_s)f\to \exp(A)f$ for $f\in \mathcal D(A)$ and deduce that this holds for all $f\in L^2$ by showing that $\exp(D_s)$ is bounded in norm (Maybe for this Fourier transform is good)
